# Jquery JS Lint error but jquery working

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Hi im' getting the following error: **Problem at line 3 character 14: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined Implied global: $ 2** Check out the working script [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/makingthings/7TVfh/)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to fix it for jsFiddle (although I think the error was more of some kind of JSLint warning as your code appeared to be working fine) - replace:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
```

with:

```
var i = 1;
for (; i <= num; i++) {
```

Although, I would stick with your original code - remember jsFiddle is just an Alpha version.

Comment: Thanks for this. You don't think there is anything particularly wrong with the code then?

Comment: IMO your code is fine - def. a fiddle issue.